# Shell variable PROMPT_COMMAND not working as intended?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

I want my bash prompt to change depending on external conditions.

Here is excerpt from the bash manual:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND: If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

PS1: The value of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPTING below) and used as the primary prompt string.
```

In my `.bash_profile` I have following:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n ┏━━━[$(date +%H:%M)]"
export PS1="━━[\t]━━━┓\n\$ "
```

Here is what I see in terminal:

```
┏━━━[03:46]━━[03:46:52]━━━┓
$ cd ..
┏━━━[03:46]━━[03:51:37]━━━┓
$
```

As you can see, PROMPT_COMMAND doesn't get executed more than once, and remains static forever.

How can I have it executed "prior to issuing each prompt", as stated in the manual?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.3
`echo $BASH_VERSION`
    `3.2.51(1)-release`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` gets run every time, but the `$(...)` snippet is only evaluated when your `.bash_profile` is loaded. This is because the double quotes mean to still expand variables and commands.

If you use single quotes, the command is not substituted during the execution of `.bash_profile`, it is evaluated when the `PROMPT_COMMAND` is run.

Comment: Thank you. This works as expected: export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n "┏━━━[$(date +%H:%M)]"'

Comment: I just discovered that it is possible to evaluate code in the PS1 as well `PS1="[\$(date +%H:%M)] \u@\w\ $ "`. It makes PROMPT_COMMAND superfluous.

Comment: @Sergei That's awesome, I'm going to use that. But for what you're doing (since it's the line above) I'd recommend using `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `date` call got evaluated when you set `PROMPT_COMMAND` so it is forever stuck at the  time that you ran:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n ┏━━━[$(date +%H:%M)]"
```

Try defining a function instead and assigning that to PROMPT_COMMAND:

```
function prompt_command() {
    PS1="┏━━━[$(date +%H:%M)]━━[\t]━━━┓\n\$ "
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

You can also use `\@` for the current time in 12-hour AM/PM format in your prompt. So:

```
function prompt_command() {
    PS1="┏━━━[\@]━━[\t]━━━┓\n\$ "
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Would give you:

```
┏━━━[06:17 PM]━━[18:17:57]━━━┓
$
```

And while we're talking bash customizations let me put in a plug for the excellent [bash-it project](https://github.com/revans/bash-it) -- it's a bash equivalent to [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and it comes with a bunch of helper functions for theme creation. You might find it makes this sort of thing a little easier.

Comment: Thank you! You answer is very useful (the function is a great idea indeed!), but I accepted the first one, because it clearly explains what's going on from the technical standpoint. bash-it is a goldmine.

Comment: @Sergei no worries. That's how it works around here. You should pick the answer you think best represents the solution to your posed question!